# Copy (draw) one image inside region of another image in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Is it possible to copy (draw) one image into region of another in Matlab? I need not only copy a matrix part, but copy with interpolation, i.e. passing fraction coordinates.

Comment: If you are talking about so called in-painting, it was asked on [DSP](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1623/implementing-discrete-poisson-equation-wtih-neumann-boundary-condition/1655#1655).

Answer (score 3):

You can "blend" images using alpha channel (or fractional mask).
Suppose you have `master` the large image, `region` the smaller image to be blended into `master` and `alpha` a fractional mask (the same size as `region`), where `alpha=0` indicates that the corresponding output pixel should be taken from `master`, and `alpha=1` indicates a pixel to be taken from `region` (`alpha` can be fractional to indicate a blend).
I assume `master`, `region` and `alpha` has the same width and height, and are of type `double`.
Then

```
 >> blend = bsxfun( @times, master, 1-alpha) + bsxfun( @times, region, alpha )
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to achieve fractional spatial translation?

Comment: use `tformarray` to translate `region` with respect to `master` defining linear or cubic interpolation with fractional translation should give you the result you want. See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/performing-general-2-d-spatial-transformations.html#f12-28504) for more info.